# How I can solve $near query in mongoddb adbpter query building issue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, keystonejs

I'm trying to create a nearby searching platform with  [keystone.js](https://www.keystonejs.com/)

But the nearby queries not working with the keystone js.

How I can run mongoose $nearSphere query or aggregation queries in the keystone?

Hereby added my best try and errors.

**Index.js**

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: './.env'
});

const {
  Keystone
} = require('@keystonejs/keystone');
const {
  GraphQLApp
} = require('@keystonejs/app-graphql');
const {
  AdminUIApp
} = require('@keystonejs/app-admin-ui');
const {
  PasswordAuthStrategy
} = require('@keystonejs/auth-password');
const {
  MongooseAdapter
} = require('@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose');

const initialiseData = require('./initial-data');

const {
  Post,
  User,
  Category,
  SubCategory,
  Comment,
  ForgottenPasswordToken,

} = require('./schema');

const PROJECT_NAME = 'rentospot';
const keystone = new Keystone({
  appVersion: {
    version: '1.0.0',
    addVersionToHttpHeaders: false,
    access: false,
  },
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Default to true in production
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
    sameSite: false,
  },
  cookieSecret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  adapter: new MongooseAdapter({
    mongoUri: 'mongodb+srv://*******:******.mongodb.net/my-app-key-stone'
  }),
  onConnect: process.env.CREATE_TABLES !== 'true' && initialiseData,
});


const postList = keystone.createList('Post', Post);
keystone.createList('Category', Category);
keystone.createList('SubCategory', SubCategory);
keystone.createList('Comment', Comment);
keystone.createList('User', User);
keystone.createList('ForgottenPasswordToken', ForgottenPasswordToken);
const authStrategy = keystone.createAuthStrategy({
  type: PasswordAuthStrategy,
  list: 'User',
});
const extendSchema = {
  queries: [{
    schema: 'nearBy: [Post]',
    resolver: async(_) => {
      try {
        const {
          adapter
        } = postList;
        const result = await adapter.find({
          // "feature": true,
          "venue.location": {
            "$nearSphere": {
              "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [12, 75],
              },
              "$minDistance": 0,
              "$maxDistance": 500,
            },
          }
        });

        console.log(result)
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("errrrrrrrrrrrrrror:  ", e)
        return null
      }
    },
  }, ]
};
keystone.extendGraphQLSchema(extendSchema)
module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [new GraphQLApp(),
    new AdminUIApp({
      name: PROJECT_NAME,
      enableDefaultRoute: true,
      authStrategy
    })
  ],
};
```

**Schema.js**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid');
const { sendEmail } = require('./emails');

const {
    File,
    Text,
    Slug,
    Relationship,
    Select,
    Password,
    Checkbox,
    CalendarDay,
    DateTime,
    Integer
} = require('@keystonejs/fields');

const { S3Adapter } = require('@keystonejs/file-adapters');
const { AuthedRelationship } = require('@keystonejs/fields-authed-relationship');
const { formatISO } = require('date-fns');
const { Wysiwyg } = require('@keystonejs/fields-wysiwyg-tinymce');
const  LocationGoogle  = require('./LocationGoogle');

const fileAdapter = new S3Adapter({
    bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    folder: process.env.S3_PATH,
    publicUrl: ({ filename }) =>
        // `https://${process.env.CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID}.cloudfront.net/${process.env.S3_PATH}/${filename}`,
        `https://${process.env.CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID}/${process.env.S3_PATH}/${filename}`,
    s3Options: {
        // Optional paramaters to be supplied directly to AWS.S3 constructor
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        accessKeyId: process.env.API_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: process.env.REGION
    },
    uploadParams: ({ id }) => ({
        Metadata: {
            keystone_id: `${id}`,
        },
    }),
});

// Access control functions
const userIsAdmin = ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => Boolean(user && user.isAdmin);
const userOwnsItem = ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => {
    if (!user) {
        return false;
    }
    return { id: user.id };
};
const userIsCurrentAuth = ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => Boolean(user); // item will be undefined for anonymous user

const userIsAdminOrOwner = auth => {
    const isAdmin = access.userIsAdmin(auth);
    const isOwner = access.userOwnsItem(auth);
    return isAdmin ? isAdmin : isOwner;
};

const access = { userIsAdmin, userIsCurrentAuth, userOwnsItem, userIsAdminOrOwner };

// Read: public / Write: admin
const DEFAULT_LIST_ACCESS = {
    create: access.userIsCurrentAuth,
    read: true,
    update: access.userIsAdminOrOwner,
    delete: access.userIsAdmin,
};

exports.User = {
    access: {
        update: access.userIsCurrentAuth,
        delete: access.userIsAdmin,
    },
    fields: {
        name: { type: Text },
        dob: {
            type: CalendarDay,
            format: 'do MMMM yyyy',
            dateFrom: '1901-01-01',
            dateTo: formatISO(new Date(), { representation: 'date' }),
        },
        phone: { 
            type: Text, 
            isUnique: true,
            access: { read: access.userIsCurrentAuth },
            // hooks: {
            //     validateInput:
            // }
            },
        email: { type: Text, isUnique: true, access: { read: access.userIsCurrentAuth } },
        password: { type: Password, isRequired: true },
        isAdmin: { type: Checkbox, access: { update: access.userIsAdmin } },
        twitterHandle: { type: Text },
        image: { type: File, adapter: fileAdapter },
    },
    hooks: {
        afterChange: async ({ updatedItem, existingItem }) => {
            if (existingItem && updatedItem.password !== existingItem.password) {
                const url = process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';

                const props = {
                    recipientEmail: updatedItem.email,
                    signinUrl: `${url}/signin`,
                };

                const options = {
                    subject: 'Your password has been updated',
                    to: updatedItem,
                    from: process.env.MAILGUN_FROM,
                    domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
                    apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
                };

                await sendEmail('password-updated.jsx', props, options);
            }
        },
    },
};

// exports.Organiser = {
//   access: DEFAULT_LIST_ACCESS,
//   fields: {
//     user: { type: Relationship, ref: 'User' },
//     order: { type: Integer },
//     role: { type: Text },
//   },
// };

// TODO: We can't access the existing item at the list update level yet,
// read access needs to check if event is "active" or if the user is admin
// read: ({ existingItem, authentication }) => access.userIsAdmin({ authentication }) || !!(existingItem && existingItem.status === 'active'),

exports.Post = {
    access: DEFAULT_LIST_ACCESS,
    fields: {
        title: { type: Text },
        slug: { type: Slug, from: 'title' },
        author: {
            type: AuthedRelationship,
            ref: 'User',
            isRequired: true,
            access: {
                read: userIsCurrentAuth,
                update: userIsAdmin,
            },
        },
        status: {
            type: Select,
            defaultValue: 'published',
            options: [
                { label: 'Draft', value: 'draft' },
                { label: 'Published', value: 'published' },
            ],
        },
        feature: { type: Checkbox, access: { update: access.userIsAdmin } },
        assured: { type: Checkbox, access: { update: access.userIsAdmin } },
        posted: { type: DateTime, format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' },
        categories: {
            type: Relationship,
            ref: 'Category',
            many: false,
        },
        subCategories: {
            type: Relationship,
            ref: 'SubCategory',
            many: true,
        },
        description: { type: Wysiwyg },
        venue: {
            type: LocationGoogle,
            googleMapsKey: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY,
            // hooks: {
                // resolveInput: async ({ originalInput }) => {
                //     try {
                //         const placeId = originalInput.venue;
                //         if (typeof placeId === 'undefined') {
                //             // Nothing was passed in, so we can bail early.
                //             return undefined;
                //         }
                //         const r = await fetch(
                //             `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=${placeId}&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}`
                //         )
                //         const response = await r.json()
                //         if (response.results && response.results[0]) {
                //             const { place_id, formatted_address } = response.results[0];
                //             const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                //             return {
                //                 googlePlaceID: place_id,
                //                 formattedAddress: formatted_address,
                //                 lat,
                //                 lng,
                //                 loc: {
                //                     type: "Point",
                //                     coordinates: [lng, lat]
                //                 }
                //             };
                //         }
                //         return null;
                //     }
                //     catch (e) {
                //         console.log("error:", e)
                //     }
                // },

                // validateInput: async (x) => {
                //     console.log("---------------------------------item 2-------------------------------------- : ",x);
                // },
                // beforeChange: async (x) => {
                //     console.log("========", x)

                // },
                // afterChange: async (x) => {
                //     console.log("++++", x)
                // }
            // },
        },
        locationAddress: { type: Text },
        locationDescription: { type: Text },
        createdby: {
            type: AuthedRelationship,
            ref: 'User',
            isRequired: true,
            access: {
                read: userIsCurrentAuth,
                update: userIsAdmin,
            },
        },
        image: {
            type: File,
            adapter: fileAdapter,
            hooks: {
                beforeChange: async ({ existingItem }) => {
                    if (existingItem && existingItem.image) {
                        await fileAdapter.delete(existingItem.image);
                    }
                },
            },
        },

    },
    hooks: {
        afterDelete: ({ existingItem }) => {
            if (existingItem.image) {
                fileAdapter.delete(existingItem.image);
            }
        },
    },
    adminConfig: {
        defaultPageSize: 20,
        defaultColumns: 'title, status',
        defaultSort: 'title',
    },
    labelResolver: item => item.title,
};

exports.Category = {
    // access:  userIsAdmin,
    fields: {
        name: { type: Text },
        slug: { type: Slug, from: 'name' },
        image: {
            type: File,
            adapter: fileAdapter,
            hooks: {
                beforeChange: async ({ existingItem }) => {
                    if (existingItem && existingItem.image) {
                        await fileAdapter.delete(existingItem.image);
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

exports.SubCategory = {
    // access:  userIsAdmin,
    fields: {
        name: { type: Text },
        slug: { type: Slug, from: 'name' },
        categories: {
            type: Relationship,
            ref: 'Category',
            many: false,
        },
        image: {
            type: File,
            adapter: fileAdapter,
            hooks: {
                beforeChange: async ({ existingItem }) => {
                    if (existingItem && existingItem.image) {
                        await fileAdapter.delete(existingItem.image);
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

exports.Comment = {
    access: {
        create: userIsCurrentAuth,
        update: userIsAdminOrOwner,
    },
    fields: {
        body: { type: Text, isMultiline: true },
        originalPost: {
            type: Relationship,
            ref: 'Post',
        },
        author: {
            type: AuthedRelationship,
            ref: 'User',
            isRequired: true,
            access: {
                create: userIsAdmin,
                update: userIsAdmin,
            },
        },
        posted: { type: CalendarDay },
    },
    labelResolver: item => item.body,
};


// exports.Talk = {
//   access: DEFAULT_LIST_ACCESS,
//   fields: {
//     name: { type: Text },
//     event: { type: Relationship, ref: 'Event.talks' },
//     speakers: { type: Relationship, ref: 'User.talks', many: true },
//     isLightningTalk: { type: Checkbox },
//     description: { type: Wysiwyg },
//   },
// };

// exports.Rsvp = {
//   access: {
//     create: true,
//     read: true,
//     update: ({ authentication: { item } }) => {
//       if (!item) {
//         return false;
//       }
//       return { user: { id: item.id } };
//     },
//     delete: access.userIsAdmin,
//   },
//   fields: {
//     event: { type: Relationship, ref: 'Event' },
//     user: { type: Relationship, ref: 'User' },
//     status: { type: Select, options: 'yes, no' },
//   },
//   hooks: {
//     validateInput: async ({ context, resolvedData, existingItem }) => {
//       const { status } = resolvedData;
//       const { event: eventId } = existingItem ? existingItem : resolvedData;

//       if (status === 'no') {
//         return;
//       }

//       const { data } = await context.executeGraphQL({
//         query: `query {
//         event: Event(where: { id: "${eventId}" }) {
//           id
//           startTime
//           maxRsvps
//           isRsvpAvailable
//         }
//         allRsvps(where: { event: { id: "${eventId}" }}) {
//           id
//         }
//       }`,
//       });

//       const { event, allRsvps } = data;

//       if (
//         !event ||
//         !event.isRsvpAvailable ||
//         !event.startTime ||
//         new Date() > new Date(event.startTime) ||
//         allRsvps.length >= event.maxRsvps
//       ) {
//         throw 'Error rsvping to event';
//       }
//     },
//   },
// };

// exports.Sponsor = {
//   access: DEFAULT_LIST_ACCESS,
//   fields: {
//     name: { type: Text },
//     website: { type: Text },
//     logo: { type: CloudinaryImage, adapter: cloudinaryAdapter },
//   },
// };

exports.ForgottenPasswordToken = {
    access: {
        create: true,
        read: true,
        update: access.userIsAdmin,
        delete: access.userIsAdmin,
    },
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: Relationship,
            ref: 'User',
            access: {
                read: access.userIsAdmin,
            },
        },
        token: {
            type: Text,
            isRequired: true,
            isUnique: true,
            access: {
                read: access.userIsAdmin,
            },
        },
        requestedAt: { type: DateTime, isRequired: true },
        accessedAt: { type: DateTime },
        expiresAt: { type: DateTime, isRequired: true },
    },
    hooks: {
        afterChange: async ({ context, updatedItem, existingItem }) => {
            if (existingItem) return null;

            const now = new Date().toISOString();

            const { errors, data } = await context.executeGraphQL({
                context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                query: `
        query GetUserAndToken($user: ID!, $now: DateTime!) {
          User( where: { id: $user }) {
            id
            email
          }
          allForgottenPasswordTokens( where: { user: { id: $user }, expiresAt_gte: $now }) {
            token
            expiresAt
          }
        }
      `,
                variables: { user: updatedItem.user.toString(), now },
            });

            if (errors) {
                console.error(errors, `Unable to construct password updated email.`);
                return;
            }

            const { allForgottenPasswordTokens, User } = data;
            const forgotPasswordKey = allForgottenPasswordTokens[0].token;
            const url = process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';

            const props = {
                forgotPasswordUrl: `${url}/change-password?key=${forgotPasswordKey}`,
                recipientEmail: User.email,
            };

            const options = {
                subject: 'Request for password reset',
                to: User.email,
                from: process.env.MAILGUN_FROM,
                domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
                apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
            };

            await sendEmail('forgot-password.jsx', props, options);
        },
    },
};

exports.customSchema = {
    mutations: [
        {
            schema: 'startPasswordRecovery(email: String!): ForgottenPasswordToken',
            resolver: async (obj, { email }, context) => {
                const token = uuid();

                const tokenExpiration =
                    parseInt(process.env.RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN_EXPIRY) || 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

                const now = Date.now();
                const requestedAt = new Date(now).toISOString();
                const expiresAt = new Date(now + tokenExpiration).toISOString();

                const { errors: userErrors, data: userData } = await context.executeGraphQL({
                    context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                    query: `
            query findUserByEmail($email: String!) {
              allUsers(where: { email: $email }) {
                id
                email
              }
            }
          `,
                    variables: { email: email },
                });

                if (userErrors || !userData.allUsers || !userData.allUsers.length) {
                    console.error(
                        userErrors,
                        `Unable to find user when trying to create forgotten password token.`
                    );
                    return;
                }

                const userId = userData.allUsers[0].id;

                const result = {
                    userId,
                    token,
                    requestedAt,
                    expiresAt,
                };

                const { errors } = await context.executeGraphQL({
                    context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                    query: `
            mutation createForgottenPasswordToken(
              $userId: ID!,
              $token: String,
              $requestedAt: DateTime,
              $expiresAt: DateTime,
            ) {
              createForgottenPasswordToken(data: {
                user: { connect: { id: $userId }},
                token: $token,
                requestedAt: $requestedAt,
                expiresAt: $expiresAt,
              }) {
                id
                token
                user {
                  id
                }
                requestedAt
                expiresAt
              }
            }
          `,
                    variables: result,
                });

                if (errors) {
                    console.error(errors, `Unable to create forgotten password token.`);
                    return;
                }

                return true;
            },
        },
        {
            schema: 'changePasswordWithToken(token: String!, password: String!): User',
            resolver: async (obj, { token, password }, context) => {
                const now = Date.now();

                const { errors, data } = await context.executeGraphQL({
                    context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                    query: `
            query findUserFromToken($token: String!, $now: DateTime!) {
              passwordTokens: allForgottenPasswordTokens(where: { token: $token, expiresAt_gte: $now }) {
                id
                token
                user {
                  id
                }
              }
            }`,
                    variables: { token, now },
                });

                if (errors || !data.passwordTokens || !data.passwordTokens.length) {
                    console.error(errors, `Unable to find token`);
                    throw errors.message;
                }

                const user = data.passwordTokens[0].user.id;
                const tokenId = data.passwordTokens[0].id;

                const { errors: passwordError } = await context.executeGraphQL({
                    context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                    query: `mutation UpdateUserPassword($user: ID!, $password: String!) {
            updateUser(id: $user, data: { password: $password }) {
              id
            }
          }`,
                    variables: { user, password },
                });

                if (passwordError) {
                    console.error(passwordError, `Unable to change password`);
                    throw passwordError.message;
                }

                await context.executeGraphQL({
                    context: context.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true }),
                    query: `mutation DeletePasswordToken($tokenId: ID!) {
            deleteForgottenPasswordToken(id: $tokenId) {
              id
            }
          }
        `,
                    variables: { tokenId },
                });

                return true;
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

LocationGoogle is a directory of the files exactly @keystonejs/fields-location-google and small changes in its Implementation.js

**Implementation.js**

```
const { Implementation } = require('@keystonejs/fields');
const { MongooseFieldAdapter } = require('@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose');

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Disabling the getter of mongoose >= 5.1.0
// https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/migrating_to_5.md#checking-if-a-path-is-populated

class LocationGoogleImplementation extends Implementation {
  constructor(_, { googleMapsKey }) {
    super(...arguments);
    this.graphQLOutputType = 'LocationGoogle';

    if (!googleMapsKey) {
      throw new Error(
        'You must provide a `googleMapsKey` to LocationGoogle Field. To generate a Google Maps API please visit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key'
      );
    }

    this._googleMapsKey = googleMapsKey;
  }

  get _supportsUnique() {
    return false;
  }

  extendAdminMeta(meta) {
    return {
      ...meta,
      googleMapsKey: this._googleMapsKey,
    };
  }

  gqlOutputFields() {
    return [`${this.path}: ${this.graphQLOutputType}`];
  }

  gqlQueryInputFields() {
    return [...this.equalityInputFields('String'), ...this.inInputFields('String')];
  }

  getGqlAuxTypes() {
    return [
      `
      type Location{
        coordinates: [Float]
      },

      type ${this.graphQLOutputType} {
        location: Location
        googlePlaceID: String
        formattedAddress: String
        lat: Float
        lng: Float
      }
    `,
    ];
  }

  // Called on `User.avatar` for example
  gqlOutputFieldResolvers() {
    return {
      [this.path]: item => {
        const itemValues = item[this.path];
        if (!itemValues) {
          return null;
        }
        return itemValues;
      },
    };
  }

  async resolveInput({ resolvedData }) {
    const placeId = resolvedData[this.path];

    // NOTE: The following two conditions could easily be combined into a
    // single `if (!inputId) return inputId`, but that would lose the nuance of
    // returning `undefined` vs `null`.
    // Premature Optimisers; be ware!
    if (typeof placeId === 'undefined') {
      // Nothing was passed in, so we can bail early.
      return undefined;
    }

    if (placeId === null) {
      // `null` was specifically set, and we should set the field value to null
      // To do that we... return `null`
      return null;
    }

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=${placeId}&key=${this._googleMapsKey}`
    ).then(r => r.json());

    if (response.results && response.results[0]) {
      const { place_id, formatted_address } = response.results[0];
      const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
      return {
        location: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [lng, lat]
        },
        googlePlaceID: place_id,
        formattedAddress: formatted_address,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
      };
    }

    return null;
  }

  gqlUpdateInputFields() {
    return [`${this.path}: String`];
  }

  gqlCreateInputFields() {
    return [`${this.path}: String`];
  }
  getBackingTypes() {
    const type = `null | {
      location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [lng, lat]
      };
      googlePlaceID: string;
      formattedAddress: string;
      lat: number;
      lng: number;
      }
    `;
    return { [this.path]: { optional: true, type } };
  }
}

const CommonLocationInterface = superclass =>
  class extends superclass {
    getQueryConditions(dbPath) {
      return {
        ...this.equalityConditions(dbPath),
        ...this.inConditions(dbPath),
      };
    }
  };
class MongoLocationGoogleInterface extends CommonLocationInterface(MongooseFieldAdapter) {
  addToMongooseSchema(schema) {
    const schemaOptions = {
      type: {
        location: {
          type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
          coordinates: [Number]
        },
        googlePlaceID: String,
        formattedAddress: String,
        lat: Number,
        lng: Number,
      },
    };
    schema.add({
      [this.path]: this.mergeSchemaOptions(schemaOptions, this.config)
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  LocationGoogleImplementation,
  MongoLocationGoogleInterface
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@keystonejs/example-projects-blank",
  "description": "A blank KeystoneJS starter project.",
  "private": true,
  "version": "5.0.15",
  "author": "The KeystoneJS Development Team",
  "repository": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/packages/create-keystone-app/example-projects/blank",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES=false DISABLE_LOGGING=false nodemon --exec keystone dev --harmony",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES=false keystone build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production keystone start",
    "create-tables": "cross-env keystone create-tables"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@arch-ui/layout": "^0.2.14",
    "@arch-ui/typography": "^0.0.18",
    "@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose": "^10.1.2",
    "@keystonejs/app-admin-ui": "^7.3.13",
    "@keystonejs/app-graphql": "^6.2.1",
    "@keystonejs/auth-password": "^6.0.0",
    "@keystonejs/email": "^5.2.0",
    "@keystonejs/fields-authed-relationship": "^1.0.16",
    "@keystonejs/fields-location-google": "^3.2.1",
    "@keystonejs/fields-wysiwyg-tinymce": "^5.3.15",
    "@keystonejs/file-adapters": "^7.0.8",
    "@keystonejs/keystone": "^18.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

The Error screenshot attached bellow

[image]